# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError running example streaming.DirectKafkaWordCount

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to run an example program DirectKafkaWordCount using this command:

bin/run-example --packages "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.6.1,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.11:1.6.    3,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.5.0"  streaming.DirectKafkaWordCount localhost:9092  consumer    -group quickstart-events

I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/$less$colon$less
at org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.DirectKafkaWordCount$.main(DirectKafkaWordCount.scala:70)

Can you please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Do you have the correct runtime installed? Looks like it needs Scala.

Comment: I have Scala code runner version 3.3.1 -- Copyright 2002-2023, LAMP/EPFL. Other programs such SparkPi are running fine.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by performing following steps :
1. Step up kafka by performing relevant steps listed here: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart
2. Downloaded Spark source code into sparkSrc
3. Set JAVA_HOME=/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17
4. mvn clean package -DskipTests from sparkSrc/spark 
5. bin/run-example --packages "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.6.1,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.11:1.6.3,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.5.0"  streaming.DirectKafkaWordCount localhost:9092  consumer quickstart-events from spark directory